# Get days every other weeks using Enumerable.Range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to get value using Enumerable.Range in every two weeks. In this code it get the date in every weeks from selected days as i mention below on the code i select every Tuesday and  it return all Tuesday in a month but i need every two weeks of the month and i don't know how to do it. Please i need help.

```
     Dim datesThatAreSundays As IEnumerable = Enumerable.Range(start.DayOfYear, [end].Subtract(start).Days + 1).[Select](Function(n) start.AddDays(n - start.DayOfYear)).Where(Function(d) d.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thank sir for reply .. i need is to get the days in every two weeks the code above return the value in every weeks from the days i selected..

Comment: My problem is in this code            [end].Subtract(start).Days + 1).[Select](Function(n) start.AddDays(n - start.DayOfYear)).Where(Function(d) d.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday      it return the value every week and i want is every two weeks

Comment: As a starting point, this will get you a list of ten dates starting today and then every two weeks: `Dim dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) Date.Today.AddWeeks(n * 2))`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney There is [no `AddWeeks`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6847346/11683).

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, I made that up. I was thinking that would be convenient but didn't mean to type it.  Use `AddDays(n * 14)`.

Comment: but the problem is you cannot select the range of start date and end date

Comment: @GSerg ~ Maybe not, but it'd make a nice extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) do you need `Enumerable.Range`?

```vb
Public Iterator Function TheDayEveryTwoWeeks(ByVal TheDay As DayOfWeek, ByVal [start] As Date, ByVal [end] As Date) As IEnumerable(Of Date)
    Dim closest_day = [start].AddDays((TheDay - [start].DayOfWeek + 7) Mod 7)
    Dim steps_at_most = CType(([end] - closest_day).TotalDays, Integer) \ 14 + 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To steps_at_most
        Dim d As Date = closest_day.AddDays(i * 14)

        If d <= [end] Then
            Yield d
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

```vb
Dim datesThatAreTuesdays = TheDayEveryTwoWeeks(DayOfWeek.Tuesday, [start], [end])
```